# Convert a list of coordinates to an OSM path using Python

Tags: python, openstreetmap, networkx, osmnx

I have GPS coordinates recorded from vehicles for an itinerary and I need the get the path on osm so I can extract features like highways. I tried to use `ox.get_nearest_node` method for each point in my coordinates but when I try to make a graph plot using `ox.plot_graph_route` it didn't work. here is my coordinates : `itineraires.coordinates` [(-7.5822778, 33.5649577), (-7.5823494, 33.5651468), (-7.582575300000001, 33.5656444), (-7.582148500000001, 33.565812), (-7.5819043, 33.5658939), (-7.5816994, 33.5659518), (-7.581388799999999, 33.5660413), (-7.581672499999999, 33.566598), (-7.5819214, 33.5671508)]

```
import osmnx as ox

#get osmids
path = []
for point in itineraires.coordinates:
    path.append(ox.get_nearest_node(G, (point[1],point[0])))
```

here is the path after using get_nearest_node : [1261505524, 1261505524, 456520278, 5549684249, 4237637412, 4237637410, 460438855, 456520295, 1261505504]

now when i try to make a graph plot:

```
#graph plot
fig, ax = ox.plot.plot_graph_route(G, path, node_size=0, figsize=(20,18))
```

it's says:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osmnx/plot.py in plot_graph_route(G, route, route_color, route_linewidth, route_alpha, orig_dest_size, ax, **pg_kwargs)
    301     for u, v in zip(route[:-1], route[1:]):
    302         # if there are parallel edges, select the shortest in length
--> 303         data = min(G.get_edge_data(u, v).values(), key=lambda d: d["length"])
    304         if "geometry" in data:
    305             # if geometry attribute exists, add all its coords to list

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'
```

and maybe i do understand the problem here, maybe because between two nodes in the path that i create there is no edge.

Could you give an another solution that I can follow?

Comment: Without knowing how graph G  has been defined , we can do nothing,

Comment: Duplicate of     [stackoverflow :convert a list of coordinates to an osm path using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71427372/convert-a-list-of-coordinates-to-an-osm-path-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

The path must be a list of route lists

```
itineraire = [(-7.5822778, 33.5649577), (-7.5823494, 33.5651468), (-7.582575300000001, 33.5656444), (-7.582148500000001, 33.565812), (-7.5819043, 33.5658939), (-7.5816994, 33.5659518), (-7.581388799999999, 33.5660413), (-7.581672499999999, 33.566598), (-7.5819214, 33.5671508)
```

Control of the position of the points with [Folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/)

```
import folium
map = folium.Map((itineraire[0][1],itineraire[0][0]), zoom_start=13)
for pt in itineraire:
    marker = folium.Marker([pt[1], pt[0]]) #latitude,longitude
    map.add_child(marker) 
map
```

[image]

```
import osmnx as ox
# change to latitude, longitude order
itin = [(pt[1],pt[0]) for i in itineraire] #latitude longitude
# create graph
G = ox.graph_from_point(itin[0],network_type='walk')
# create the path
path = []
for first, second in zip(itin, itin[1:]):
    one = ox.get_nearest_node(G, first)
    two= ox.get_nearest_node(G, second)
    path.append(nx.shortest_path(G,one,two))
print(path)
[[1261505524], [1261505524, 1261505525, 456520278], [456520278, 1261505525, 4237637413, 5549684249], [5549684249, 4237637412], [4237637412, 4237637410], [4237637410, 460438855], [460438855, 456520295], [456520295, 1261505504]]
# plot
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_routes(G, path,edge_color='k', bgcolor='w')
```

[image]